# Optimizing MongoDB Query on GEO fence

Tags: mongodb, gps, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB to store a lot of GPS-Data (2 Mio. Documents with about 1000 GPS-Points per Document). The data looks like the following

```
{
"Data": [
{
  latitude : XXXXXX,
  longitude : XXXXXX,
  speed : XXXXXXX
}],
 "_id": ID,
" StartDayOfWeek" : X 
}
```

As you see Data is an array of GPSPoints and additional information.
I query for Documents on specific Days of the week (Sometimes I query for multiple days in which case I use $or.
Oh... lat/lon is stored as Integers
The following is my query(An example):

```
db.testNew2.aggregate(

    { $sort : {"StartDayOfWeek" : 1 }}, 


    { $match: {"$and" : [ 

        { "StartDayOfWeek" : 1},    
        { 'Data' :
        {$elemMatch:
            { "latitude" : {$gt:48143743, $lt:48143843}}}},
        { 'Data' :
        {$elemMatch:
            { "longitude" : {$gt:11554706,$lt:11554806}}}}    
        ]}},


        { $unwind : "$Data"},

    { $match: {"$and" : [ 
        { 'Data.latitude' : {$gt:48143743, $lt:48143843}},
        { 'Data.longitude' : {$gt:11554706, $lt:11554806}}    
      ]}}, 

       {$group: {
            "_id" : "$_id",
           "Traces" : { $push :"$Data"}
       }}


    )
```

As you can see I am sorting out the GPS-Points that are not within the GEO fence.
This query works fine but...and I do not know why. It seems very slow. There is an index on StartDayOfWeek and the machine is more than capable (24 GB of RAM and two 7200rpm SATA drives in RAID0).
The collection size is about 130 GB and the query takes about 3 - 5 minutes.
In the Java programme that uses that query I also use allowDiskUsage since the return values can be higher than 16 MB.

Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: You have several matches against an unindexed field. And first you match for elements, only then you unwind them only to match them again right away? Maybe it is easier to tell us what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Yes exactly. Data is not indexed. It is a very large array and I didn't think it was a good idea to blow up the index that much. Your interpretation is 100% correct. I first filter out Documents that have no GPS Point in the GEO Fence and then filter out all the specific elements in the array that are not in the GEO fence. I found several blog posts regarding this topic and they all said to do it that way sind $unwind is very expensive in terms of compute time and ressources

Comment: Additionally the Data-Array contains 99% of the data. So I would be indexing all of the Data.